# Opposite of .find(someElem), ie. want to omit children if e.target for event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to solve some dilemna, having a little bit of an issue.

So, I want to track all clicks on the page and only do something IF the e.target is not a child of some elements. So I have:

```
 jQuery('body').click(function(e){
     // some stuff
     // do some more stuff
         if(!(jQuery('#element1, #element2, #element3').find(e.target))){
             // do something extra here ONLY if the target is NOT a child
             // of any of those elements
         }

 })
```

This doesn't seem to be working. I tried some other things to get the "no found" vibe going, ala, .not, !(), etc.. couldn't. Seems to be ignoring the whole code. Even when I do a simple: just to test:

```
      // I expressly click outside this area of element1, still captures it.
     if(jQuery('#element1').find(e.target)){
         console.log('in')
         e.stopPropagation();
     // failes
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways you could go about this. The minimum change would be to append `.length` to your conditional:

```
if(!jQuery('#element1, #element2, #element3').find(e.target).length) {
    // do something extra here ONLY if the target is NOT a child
    // of any of those elements
}
```

Without `.length` the conditional will always be false because a jQuery object is a truthy value even when it does not wrap any DOM element.

A better way would probably be to do the check backwards: instead of fanning out from the target elements and walking all the DOM (which could mean visiting hundreds of descendants), why not simply walk the parents of the target (which would be a much smaller number) instead?

```
if(!$(e.target).parents().filter('#element1, #element2, #element3').length) {
    // do stuff
}
```

A third way would be to install a separate click handler on the elements you are interested in and use it to stop the click event from bubbling up to `<body>`:

```
$('#element1, #element2, #element3').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

This way you don't need a conditional inside the original handler, but I would not prefer to do this because it introduces "subtle" dependencies between handlers that at first glance look unrelated.

Comment: That is a very slow way of matching, compared to checking from the clicked target back up the hierarchy (i.e. using parents() or similar).

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: Still editing, I was writing exactly that :)

Comment: I like the walk the parents route. Just didn't occur to me, thank you very much!

Comment: OK, now you get my +1... Just didn't like to encourage a slower solution :)

Comment: @Jon - if 'if', it still failed. meaning ALL clicks still fell thru to the conditional so no matter what, all clicks were firing - what avenue would you look to as a culprit?

Comment: @jamesemanon: I would slap a breakpoint on the line with the conditional and step through with the debugger to see what exactly is going on.

Answer (score 2):

I think you search for `jQuery.parents(selector)` : [Documentation jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
   if (e.target.parents(<selector>).length == 0) {
     // Not child of selected parent => do something
   }
});
```